# SBT InputKey with property-like arguments

Tags: scala, sbt

Can someone help me create a SBT task that can support property-like arguments from command line?

```
lazy val myTask = inputKey[Unit]("my task")
myTask := {
    if (directoryOpt.isEmpty) // directoryOpt comes from an optional command line argument: directory="~/downloads"
      fullRunInputTask(inputKey, Compile, "example.MyTaskClass")
    else
      fullRunInputTask(inputKey, Compile, "example.MyTaskClass", directoryOpt.get)
}
```

Where the task can be run from command line like:

```
sbt myTask directory="~/downloads"
```

I did read the sbt doc at http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html. But it only explains how to create a task parser like `sbt myTask option1 option2` which does not quite meet my need.

UPDATE:
I used jazmit's solution since that was an easy change. It works well! I will also try Mariusz's solution and update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use environmental properties to achieve what you want quickly.

From the command line, set a property as follows:

```
sbt myTask -Ddirectory="~/downloads"
```

From the task, you can retrieve the value as follows:

```
val directory = System.getProperty("directory");
```

If you want to do something more solid with syntax checking, tab completion, etc, you can define an input task as detailed [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Input-Tasks.html).  If you need property=value syntax, you can define this using the [parser combinator library](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Parsing-Input.html), eg:

```
import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._
val myArgs: Parser[String] = "directory=" ~> StringEscapable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `project/Build.scala` along your `build.sbt` with your inputs. You can also use `Commands` instead of Tasks. Below, an example:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object CustomBuild extends Build {

def myTask = Command.args("myTask", "<name>"){ (state, args) =>

  val argMap = args.map { s => 
     s.split("=").toList match {
       case n :: v :: Nil => n -> v
     }
  }.toMap

  //println(argMap) //to see all argument pairs
  //react on name in params list
   println("Hi "+ argMap.getOrElse("name", "Unknown"))

   state //Command can modify state, so you must to return it.
  }
}
```

Now You have to add this command to you project, in build.sbt add

```
commands += myTask
```

Now you can use it:

```
> sbt "myTask name=Mario"
> Hi Mario
> sbt myTask
> sbt Hi Unknown
```

Hope, it'll help You!
more about commands:
[you can find here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Commands.html)